# Draw a line continuously using Canvas in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am using canvas to draw a line continuously. I will draw the line in relative layout. For static line, I done. For real case, I will receive data from sensor. So I don't know how to draw a line continuously as below figure. Could you suggest to me a algorithm to do it. Thank you so much. This is my code

```
//XML file
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/canvas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#d3d3d3" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code for static line

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(new HeartGraphView (this));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.canvas);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); 
        HeartGraphView v = new HeartGraphView(this);
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
        relativeLayout.addView(v);          
    }    
public class HeartGraphView  extends View {
        public HeartGraphView (Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        int[] dataX=new int[30];
        int[]  dataY=new int[30];
        public int generatRandomPositiveNegitiveValue(int max , int min) {
            Random r = new Random();
            int ii = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
            return (ii-140);
        }

    int[] dataX=new int[30];        
    int[]  dataY=new int[30];
    public int generatRandomPositiveNegitiveValue(int max , int min) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int ii = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        return (ii-140);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
        int w;
        int h;
        h=280;
        w=600;

        //Generate random
        int min = 0;
        int max = 280;

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        dataX[0]=0;
        for (int i = 0; i <  w/20 - 1; i++) {
        dataX[i+1]=(i+1)*w/20;
        dataY[w/20 - 1]=generatRandomPositiveNegitiveValue(max ,min);
        dataY[i]=dataY[i+1];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <  w/20 -1; i++) {
            // apply some transformation on data in order to map it correctly
            // in the coordinates of the canvas
            canvas.drawLine(dataX[i], h/2-dataY[i], dataX[i+1], h/2-dataY[i+1],paint);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.MULTIPLY);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            invalidate();              
        }        

    }
}
```

}
This is my result

[image]

EDIT>
As suggestion of  Frank N. Stei. I modify something:
+First, initial all elements of X axis with fixed values [0,30,60,90....] and Y axis are zero

```
    int w=600;
    for (int i = 0; i <  w/20 - 1; i++) {
    dataX[i]=i*w/20;
    dataY[i]=0;
    }
```

+ Second, with a new value comes to Y, we will put it in end of the array dataY and remove the first position:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <  w/20 - 1; i++) {
      dataY[i]=dataY[i+1];

    }
  dataY[w/20 - 1]=newValue;
```

+ Third, redraw the dataX and dataY
**Is it correct???**

Comment: Infinite loop: clear canvas, draw, go to loop

Comment: Could you show some code to do it. Thank sir

Comment: No. In my simple case, I use static data. But for real case, I will get it from a sensor. So the data will be extended. After each received data, I will draw it as the figure.

Comment: So, in your HeartView, make a loop where you modify the contents of dataY with random values in a cycle and call `invalidate();`. invalidate() calls onDraw(), so it redraws the view with the new data. Don't forget to erase the canvas, first.

Comment: Thanl you Frank N. Stein. I do it by your suggestion. But It does not similar my expected result. Do you know how to fix it.

Comment: It seems like it's too much dilated on the X axe. You could either provide more data (it will increase the detection resolution) or provide more 0 (null reading) data to fill the gaps with a flat "pause". `Or maybe it's only because you are providing random, not realistic data sets`. Also mind that a realistic data set will change in function of time. So the new data is to be appendend to the old data shifting the oldest away. Say you have (1,5,2,8,9,3) at time 0: you will have (5,2,8,9,3,5) at time 1 and (2,8,9,3,5,4) at time 2 and so on. This way you will produce a continously shifting wave.

Comment: Right. That is which I need. I think the dataY and dataX must shift from right to left. I think we must write a code to shift it. And random value can be assume. My problem is how to shift that data. Ass

Comment: Just move the next **Y** (peak) values to the previous index positions  and add the new value at the end. X remains the same for all dots, since it is the **relative** time coordinate (X0 was 0 because it was "now", now X0 is again 0, because it's **now**).

Comment: I updated my question in edit. Please show me a solution by code. If it is hard, You can make a button and when you click button the data will shift. Thank you so much

Comment: Advice you received to call `invalidate()` did not suggest calling it in your `onDraw` method, which is never a good idea. Likewise the `Thread.sleep()` call. These calls could be part of a solution but don't belong in onDraw.

Comment: @x-code:Do you have any solution. I update my code. It works now but I think it is not good as your suggestion

Comment: invalidate() has to be called after the new data has been generated, Also, instead of using 2 distinct (consecutive, same indexed) for loops, you should execute all in one loop. Also, X should **not** be scaled, since it is the time referred to the current **now** (the imaginary horizontal center of the curve is NOW).

Comment: am also struggle same issue and same output if you got it answer please send me link or sample code to mail: wingsraam@gmail.com   @user8264